# Why the constant inherits the "String?" type instead of the "String?"

Tags: swift

In the following lines of code, the `anotherVariable` constant implicitly inherits from the right side the `String` type instead of the `String?`

```
var variable: String? = "hello"

if let anotherVariable = variable { // Unwrapping
  // "anotherVariable" constant has a String type and its value is "hello"
}
```

Comment: what is your question? are you asking why variable `example` is `String?` instead of `String` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is [optional unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html). When you use `if let` on an optional value:

1. You only enter the body of the condition if the optional value is non-nil, and
2. The value that you assign it to will be of a non-optional type, so you can use it without unwrapping within the scope of the body of the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

`if let` means "unwrap", as your comment says. The unwrapped version of `String?` is `String`. Thus if `string` gets *any* value, it will be a `String` value, and the compiler knows this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Swift gives you this convention to safely unwrap optionals.  the `If let` line basically says:

- Unwrap example and assign the value to the new constant example (this may seem confusing at first)
- If it was successful, and the new constant example is equal to the unwrapped variable example, execute the code block.
- Note:  If var example was nil, the assingment would fail because nil does not equate to anything, including nil, and the code block would be skipped.

Some people find it confusing to use the same parameter name in the `if let` statement.  I prefer it that way, but it's perfectly acceptable to name it something else, for example:

```
if let unwrappedExample = example {
...   //unwrappedExample now has the unwrapped example value (if not nil)
}
```

Dealing with optionals can be a new adventure if you are new to them, but they will become second nature to you soon!  Hope this helps!